# Have anonymous edits been disabled on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, status-norepro, suggested-edits, anonymous-user

I opened a post while not logged in and I noticed that the "Improve this answer" link does not exist under any of the answers. I checked several other posts on SO and meta.SO and the behavior was consistent. It works on (some) other sites on the network though.

If I remember correctly, this used to be enabled on SO. **Has it been disabled at some point or is this a bug?**

This is how a post currently looks on Stack Overflow:

[image: Stack Overflow]

And this is the link being displayed on a post from meta SE:

[image: Meta Stack Exchange]

I made sure that:

- The Suggested Edits review queue isn't full.
- The post isn't locked.
- The post isn't very recent.
- The post doesn't have a pending edit.

Tested on Chrome and Firefox on Windows. Can anyone else reproduce this?

Answer (score 3):

The link is still there, on all posts that I tested (through multiple browsers, using a 'private' or 'incognito' browser tab, and with Firefox's container tab feature).

There can be several reasons that the link is not shown on a post, however, all outlined in the [central FAQ on suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work):

- The post isn't old enough, it needs to be 10 minutes old at least
- The queue could be full
- If the same rate limits for a normal account also apply to anonymous users *as a group*, then there could be too many suggested edits pending from anonymous users.
- The post already has a suggested edit pending on it
- Posts on child Meta sites do not support suggested edits
- The post could be locked
- You or someone else on your network tripped the anonymous suggested edits filters and has been temporarily banned from suggesting more.

I know you stated you tested several of these possibilities, but you can't check all of these. The last one is not shown anywhere that even moderators can check, for example. You checked on Meta sites, for example, but Meta sites don't have suggested edits.

Comment: Yes, the link seems to be back. I did check this post and tested all those cases before posting as I've already mentioned in the question. This might've been a temporary bug, which might still be worth investigating.

Comment: @41686d6564: you are not the only user on your network. Did you check with all of those to see if anyone has been making dodgy anonymous suggested edits lately?

Comment: Nope, that could be it. That being said, I did actually _suspect_ this might be the case (because I'm using a VPN) so I disconnected the VPN and tried again (before posting the question) and the behavior was consistent. Now, that the link is back, it's back on the same network as before. You're still right though, I can't be 100% sure; it might have been a temporary IP ban (although quite unlikely that both IP addresses were affected).

Comment: Also, I am in fact the only person using my network (when not connected to a VPN, of course).

Comment: @41686d6564: but did you clear the cache before loading the page again? There's a lot of caching going on, especially for anonymous visitors to the site.

Comment: If you mean the browser cache, I was on an Incognito window. I did close Incognito before switching to my original network, then opened it again to retry without VPN (AFAIK, that equals fresh cache). I'm not saying your theory is wrong though. You still could be right. If it was indeed an IP ban (on the VPN's IP address), the system probably has a way to (guess?) that someone using that IP has switched to a different network and "extend" the ban. In fact, that's the most probable explanation besides it being a bug.

Comment: In my experience, being IP edit banned lasts an entire week. Unfortunately I can’t remember what that looked like, if it actually showed the edit button or not. (Ps it’s extremely easy to get blocked like this without doing anything wrong; in my case it was an automatic ban based off the content of the suggested edit—reviewers never saw the edit.)

Comment: Suggestion queue was full a few hours ago. This could have been the reason of the issue.